# What is this math term called?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

You know how $2+2 =4$, $2\times 2 = 4$ and also $2^2 = 4$? What is the mathematical term for that when a number can have many operations and the same answer? And are there any other numbers with that situation, like $1$, because $1 \times 1 = 1$, $1 \div 1 = 1$, $1^2 = 1$. And obviously $0$.

So can you please answer this question

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there isn't one. Why should there be a mathematical term?

Comment: I'm not really sure what pattern you're getting at since the ones for 2 and 1 you described are different. $2/2 \neq 4$ and $1+1 \neq 1$.

Comment: I believe such occurrences are typically called coincidences.

Comment: I think its unlikely that to have a technical name, however it can be a fun little exercise to work these things out yourself. For example, suppose we want $+$ and $\times$ to coincide. Then we can write the following. $x+x = xx$ iff $2x = x^2$ iff $x^2-2x=0$ iff $x(x-2)=0$ iff $x=0$ or $x=2$. Also, if you have a *particular* such question that you cannot solve, feel free to ask another question and lots of people are likely to help.

Comment: Some people call them Karl käfer equations

Comment: @KarlKäfer, yes but the set of all such people is a *sub*singleton...

Comment: Better than no one, innit

Comment: There are lots of modular solutions, e.g. $\rm\, mod\ 4n\!:\ 2n+2n \equiv 2n * 2n \equiv (2n)^{2n} \equiv 0,\,$ for example $\rm\, mod\ 100\!:\ 50+50\equiv 50*50\equiv 50^{50}$

Answer (score 1):

Solving for the proposed relations:

$x+x = y$

$x^2 = y = 2x$

So the only numbers are $2$ and $0$, but $0^0$ is not $0$, hence the only number with this property is called two.

Now, for the second one, $x/x$ is always $1$.

There is no mathematical term for numbers being the result of interesting operations. In fact it can be proved that every number is interesting in some sense. If you're interested in number patterns, take a look at http://oeis.org/